# void** cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++, user-interface, glfw

I'm getting an error while compiling this code. The error says `'&((WidgetButton*)this)->WidgetButton::callback' cannot be used as a function`. I don't know why. What did I do wrong?

The explain a little more. The purpose of this code is to be able to add a button into a GUI, in a OOP way. `callback` is the function given to the constructor which will be called when the button is activated (clicked). Although right now it activates only when you press space, for the purpose of making sure the GUI works with `Widget` derived classes.

**WidgetButton.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "cgl.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class WidgetButton : Widget
{
    public:
        WidgetButton(GLFWwindow* window, void* callback, int sender);

        void onUpdate(double delta);
        void onRender();

    private:
        void* callback;
        int sender;
};
```

**WidgetButton.cpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "WidgetButton.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

WidgetButton::WidgetButton(GLFWwindow* window, void* callback, int sender) : Widget(window)
{
    this->callback = callback;
    this->sender = sender;
}

void WidgetButton::onUpdate(double delta)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(this->window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE))
        (&this->callback)(sender); //This is where the error happens
}

void WidgetButton::onRender()
{

}
```

Comment: Pointers are not the same thing as function pointers, and you should really use something better than `void *` in C++. `void *` should not be used to store function pointers.

Comment: Well, how do I define a function pointer then? It looks to me like <code>void**</code> is the same as a function pointer.

Comment: First of all, you can inline code with backticks. Second, is it ok to have one specific callback signature? If so, a normal function pointer is easily good enough: `void (*callback)(int)`

Comment: Also, I fixed it. All I did was replace all `void*`s with `void (*callback)(int)`s. I also changed `(&this->callback)(sender);` to `this->callback(this->sender)`.

Comment: It's the key to the left of the 1 key. `

Answer (score 0):

`void *` is a distinct type from something that can hold a function. It is bad to try to put a function pointer or similar into it. C++ has several options, and the simplest one if you're coming from C or haven't dealt with templates too much is all that's necessary here, a function pointer:

```
void (*callback)(int);
```

Onward, it's also possible to do the same with a simple template:

```
template<typename F>
F callback;
```

Next, it's also possible to allow other types with some template work. This is the most generic way, but it's able to be tuned according to which parts you want generic:

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
...
Ret (*callback)(Args...);
```

Finally, C++ provides `std::function`, which you can use here as well, but it's really most suited for more complex purposes with the large overhead:

```
std::function<void(int)> callback;
```

Comment: When I do that and do `WidgetButton *button = new WidgetButton(window, callback, 0)` (callback being a void function with 1 integer as the parameters), it says `no matching function for call to 'WidgetButton::WidgetButton(GLFWwindow*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, int)'`. What happend?

Comment: @MonetR.Adams, First of all, I recommend not using pointers and `new` whenever possible: `WidgetButton button(window, callback, 0);`. Secondly, it looks like you're trying to pass in an overloaded function. If you must pass in an overloaded function, you should cast it to the right type (basically to the same type as taken in the function you're calling). `static_cast<void(*)(int)>(callback)` should work for that.

Comment: The function "callback" is inside a class and is not overloaded. When I cast it with `static_cast<void(*)(int)>(callback)` it just says `invalid static_cast from type '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to type 'void (*) (int)'`.

Comment: @MonetR.Adams, If it's inside a class, you need a member function pointer (`void(ClassName::*)(int)`) or, in the case of `std::function`, you have to account for the `this` parameter. Or you could just make it static or `std::bind` the object and hold that in a `std::function` or the single template parameter option.

Comment: I don't want to bind a specific class to the button class (as there will be multiple GUI classes which will use it). What's the best way to get a function pointer that works with any class?

Comment: Actually, it was overloaded. But it still has the same error with the cast.

Comment: @MonetR.Adams, If it's an instance member function, it needs some object to operate on. There's no way around that. You'll have to give it an object at some point, either by binding one and pretending in the class that it's a normal function, passing one and being able to change it, or using a preset object.

Comment: I fixed it. I just went into the DLL that defines the GUI class and made `onButtonPress(int)` virtual. So if the GUI class does't contain it, the button will call the function although it just wont do anything. The only problem is that the button object is dynamically allocated because it tried to call the constructor as soon as it was defined in the header, which is invalid since the constructor takes 3 arguments. I might look into initializing it with a separate function to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: @MonetR.Adams, Sounds suspiciously like you need a constructor initializer list.